# Is generating custom authentication token for WCF service requests a good practice?

Tags: authentication, web-service, wcf, token

I have public WCF web service which works over https. There are lots of technical restrictions on client side, so I can't use any advanced schemes like oauth. I have registered users and some of them can access WCF service using their credentials.
Should client pass credentials with every request or I can design login method which generates some token that can be used to access my service? Which is more secure? What are the requirments for token?

Comment: preventing replay attacks is one thing you may want to consider...

Comment: @makerofthings7 as far as I know https is not replayable, is it?